Surjective submersions
I'm struggeling with the following:

If $F: M\to N$ is a surjective submersion, then for every $q\in N$ there is an open $U\subseteq N$ and a smooth function $g:U \subseteq N \to M$ such that $F(g(y)) = q$ for all $y\in U$.

Can't we just say the following:
since $F$ is a surjection, for every $q\in N$ there is a $p_0 \in M$ such that $F(p_0) = q$, so take $g: U=N \to M ; \: \:  g(q) = p_0$. Then $g$ is constant, so it's smooth and we're done?

If $|N| > 1$, the function you're defining is not constant. For each $q \in N$ you can choose $p \in M$ such that $F(p)=q$, but this $p$ will necessarily be different for different choices of $q$.

@J.C. Im sorry if this is an "dumb" question, but if $g$ maps every $q$ to $p_0$, then how is $g$ not a constant mapping?

For a given $q \in N$ you can choose $p_0 \in M$ such that $F(p_0)=q$, and you can define the constant map $g:N \to M$ sending everything to $p_0$, but then this map does not satisfy $F(g(y))=y$ for all $y \in N$. If this is still confusing, it might help to think through the example $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $F(x,y)=x$.
Actually, I realized your statement really says $F(g(y)) = q$, in which case what you're doing does indeed work. Is this really what you want or is it a typo? The condition $F(g(y))=y$ would be more natural, asking for what is usually known as a "local section".

@J.C. I think that the question may contain a typo. I was already confused. Thanks anyway!
